# Error in update with Entity Framework .NET

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

When the system performs an update on a system entity, it displays the error below:

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'The instance of entity type 'CARTS' cannot be tracked because another instance with the same key value for {'Id'} is already being tracked. When attaching existing entities, ensure that only one entity instance with a given key value is attached. Consider using 'DbContextOptionsBuilder.EnableSensitiveDataLogging' to see the conflicting key values.'

I'm using .NET 7.0 and EntityFramework 6.0.

My MauiProgram.cs:

```
    builder.Services.AddDbContext<AppDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlite(DesignTimeDbContextFactory.GetConnectionString(config)));

    builder.Services.AddScoped(typeof(IBaseRepository<>), typeof(BaseRepository<>));
    builder.Services.AddScoped<IUserService, UserService>();
    builder.Services.AddScoped<ICategoryService, CategoryService>();
    builder.Services.AddScoped<IProductService, ProductService>();
    builder.Services.AddScoped<IBannerService, BannerService>();
    builder.Services.AddScoped<IAuthorService, AuthorService>();
    builder.Services.AddScoped<IConfigService, ConfigService>();
    builder.Services.AddScoped<IMeasureService, MeasureService>();
    builder.Services.AddScoped<ICartService, CartService>();
    builder.Services.AddScoped<IItemCartService, ItemCartService>();
    builder.Services.AddScoped<IBranchService, BranchService>();
```

My BaseRepository.cs:

```
public virtual IQueryable<TEntity> GetAll()
{
    return _context.Set<TEntity>().AsNoTracking();
}

public virtual void Update(TEntity obj)
{
    _context.Entry(obj).State = Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.EntityState.Modified;
}
```

Local where call the update:

```
cart.orderId = cart.Id;
cart.Payment = payment;
cart.Status = "Awaiting Payment";
if (cpf.Length == 14)
{
    cart.CPF = cpf;
}
cartService.Update(cart);
```

Comment: Where do you get the cart from?

Comment: You are using Entity.  The Entity model has a primary key and error indicates the key already exists.  Update should work if ID is already in the database.  Most likely the ID is not in the database and you need to Add instead of Update.  Also see following to enhance the error message like the exception says : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.dbcontextoptionsbuilder.enablesensitivedatalogging?view=efcore-7.0

Comment: If you want to update loaded entities *don't* use AsNoTracking. EF's `Update` doesn't write to the database, it starts tracking detached objects in either the Added or Modified state. The code you posted breaks EF at the most basic level. EF neither has no needs CRUD classes named XyzRepository. Naming your custom method `Update`, when DbContext itself has an `Update` makes it even harder to understand what's broken

Comment: Frankly, just delete the repository classes completely. A DbContext is a higher level abstraction than low-level CRUDs. It's a multi-entity Unit of Work, not a database connection. Use EF properly and try to add abstractions ONLY if you find out you need them.

Comment: I guess you get another instance of 'cart' from the DB (maybe to compare to the new one?), and therefore the one you retrieved from the DB is in the change tracker. When updating the new one with the same ID, results in the error. Try updating the one you retrieved from the DB and update that one using ` _repo.Context.Entry(old).CurrentValues.SetValues(new);` or get the old entity from the DB using .asNoTracking()

Comment: @jdweng the funny thing is that EF's own Update would handle add/modify without problem

Comment: The cart is getting in this function: 
            `CARTS? cart = _repo.GetAll().Where(c => c.Status == "Opened").Include(c => c.ItensCarts).FirstOrDefault();`

I added the EnableSensitiveDataLogging and retorned this error:

`System.InvalidOperationException: 'The instance of entity type 'CARTS' cannot be tracked because another instance with the key value '{Id: 141}' is already being tracked. When attaching existing entities, ensure that only one entity instance with a given key value is attached.'`